# CustomUserAgent does not work at Safari 7

Tags: safari

I upgraded My MacBook Pro to OSX 10.9 hence my safari was upgraded to 7 with good expectation.

First thing I observed that Safari 7 does not take my CustomUserAgent from ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist.

I stopped safari, made manually CustomUserAgent entry in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist  and restarted safari again but Safari does not take CustomUserAgent and continued with Default value setting in Developer Menu. Same setting used to work  with Safari 6.0.5/6.1.

Could you guys help me to figure out this issue?

Regards,
Anand Choubey

Answer (score 0):

10.9 Preferences are cached. Please check below link for more details.
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20130908042828630

I suggest, modify Preferences should be done either use  defaults command or
CFPreferencesSetValue in programming.

Preferences should not be modified through hand.

Regards,
Anand Choubey